# js bundles and scope confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm trying to better understand scoping within a webpacked bundle with node components and other js.

Suppose my entry imports eight files to be bundled: 
    // entry point 
    import './components/file1';
    import './components/file2';
    ...
    import './components/file8';

And suppose in file1.js I have:

```
// file1.js

let bubbles = () => {
  console.log('likes cats');
};

// or

function bubbles() {
  console.log('likes cats');
}
```

Why then, if I have this in files8 (imported last), does it throw an undefined error? How do I call functions declared in other imports?

```
// file8.js

bubbles(); // fails in any file other than file1.js where it's declared.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `export` explicitly on functions/primitives you're intending to access from the outside:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export